# Why does my functional component not re-render when its prop changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am storing an array in my parent component which I am passing to child component to render, along with a function that allows the child component to modify and re-render by updating state of the array.

Parent

```
function App() {
  const [matrix, setMatrix] = useState([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
  const [rows, setRows] = useState(3);
  const [cols, setCols] = useState(3);

  const setElement = (index, num) => {
    const tempMatrix = matrix;
    tempMatrix[index] = num;
    setMatrix(tempMatrix);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Matrix matrix={matrix} cols={cols} setElement={setElement} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Parent Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5zZ0.png)

Child

```
const Matrix = ({ matrix, cols, setElement }) => {
  const displayMethod = () => {
    return matrix.map((element, index) => {
      if ((index + 1) % cols === 0) {
        return (
          <span>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={element}
              onChange={(event) =>
                setElement(index, parseInt(event.target.value))
              }
            />
            <br />
          </span>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <input
            type="text"
            value={element}
            onChange={(event) =>
              setElement(index, parseInt(event.target.value))
            }
          />
        );
      }
    });
  };

  return <div className="matrix">{displayMethod()}</div>;
};
```

[Child Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOJeC.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please don't paste images of code, paste code instead. See how do I ask a good question [ask].

Comment: You need to post a minimal but complete example of the problem code *here* as formatted text. Not linked, not in images. Other sites can go down or the referenced content could change, making this question invalid.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The issue here is state mutation. `tempMatrix` is a reference to the `matrix` state and `tempMatrix[index] = num;` is a mutation. The same state reference is saved back into state.

```
const setElement = (index, num) => {
  const tempMatrix = matrix; // <-- reference to state
  tempMatrix[index] = num;   // <-- state mutation!!
  setMatrix(tempMatrix);     // <-- same reference saved back into state
}
```

The child component doesn't rerender because the the `matrix` state and passed prop never changes shallow object reference equality.

## Solution

A ***new*** array reference should be created so React's reconciliation process can work. Use a functional state update to map the previous `matrix` array to the next state. Use the mapped array index to update the specific element.

```
const setElement = (index, num) => {
  setMatrix((matrix) =>
    matrix.map((value, i) => (i === index ? num : value))
  );
};
```

[image: Edit why-does-my-functional-component-not-re-render-when-its-prop-changes]